# Mysql order by field with given values which has NULL in between

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to sort a query by given values like this:

`ORDER BY FIELD(items.stock_id, 1, 5, NULL, 3, 6)`

But it seems it doesn't work and null comes first or last depending on it being descending or not.

The order is not always the same hence `[1,5,NULL,3,6]` changes every time and is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIELD-function does not match the NULL-stock_id as NULL value (NULL does not have any value).

You could use a magic number:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(IFNULL(items.stock_id,-1), 1, 5, -1, 3, 6)
```

Comment: nvm that was my bad. Thank you.